# Create alias of a command with sudo

Tags: alias

I would like to create an alias of the below command with sudo like below.

```
alias /usr/bin/vmstat='sudo /usr/bin/vmstat'
```

is it possible to create something like that for a user?

Comment: That will work in zsh. Which shell are you using?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve here? According to `man vmstat` *vmstat does not require special permissions*

Comment: I have deployed a monitoring system and that runs a command /usr/bin/vmstat 1 3 to get CPU usage but that command returns out with error of /proc not mounted but when I run sudo /usr/bin/vmstat 1 3 i return the result correctly.

Comment: @MirzaSajawalBaig please edit your question to include that information, and provide the exact error message as well. Which monitoring system is it?

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, an alias is just a name, but not a path (since aliases are stored in memory).

Here are some examples from my own system:

```
alias cte='crontab -e'
alias scte='sudo crontab -e'
# if I wanted a separate alias for 'sudo htop' I would have called the following alias shtop
alias htop='sudo htop'
```

In your example, for Bash you would need to do:

```
alias vmstat='sudo /usr/bin/vmstat'
```

Then the `vmstat` command would run with `sudo` by default.

You just need to decide which alias name you want to allocate to which command - with or without `sudo`.

Comment: I need to run the exact command /usr/bin/vmstat  but with sudo privileges,
when I run /usr/bin/vmstat command then sudo /usr/bin/vmstat will return the output.

Comment: Yes you can't use `/` in alias in Bash - see my answer.

Comment: is there any alternative way to do that?

Comment: No not with Bash, but maybe with Zsh as Muru stated.